# How are names and function bodies stored in CPython Code Objects?

Tags: python, c, compiler-construction, bytecode, cpython

I have a python script.

```
def hello(self):
    return 6
print hello()
```

Disassembling after compiling in CPython I get

```
>>> c = compile(open('hello.py').read(), 'hello.py', 'exec')
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(c)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object hello at 0x1006c9230, file "hello.py", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (hello)

  3           9 LOAD_NAME                0 (hello)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             15 PRINT_ITEM
             16 PRINT_NEWLINE
             17 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

I'm curious how the `<code object hello at 0x1006c9230 ...>` is stored inside the CPython code object. There is the `co_code` function but that only prints out the bytecode instructions. If I serialize the CPython code object I get

```
>>> import marshal
>>> marshal.dumps(c)
'c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00s\x15\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x84\x00\x00Z\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00GHd\x01\x00S(\x02\x00\x00\x00c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\n\x00\x00\x00d\x01\x00}\x01\x00|\x01\x00S(\x02\x00\x00\x00Ni\x06\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selft\x01\x00\x00\x00x(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x08\x00\x00\x00hello.pyt\x05\x00\x00\x00hello\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06\x01N(\x01\x00\x00\x00R\x02\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x08\x00\x00\x00hello.pyt\x08\x00\x00\x00<module>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\t\x03'
```

I know that

```
def hello(self):
    return 6
```

is stored somewhere in the dump because if I change it to `return 5`, one byte in the dump switches from 6 to 5.

1) Is there a way I can access the function body from the CPython code object. The closest I can get it `c.names` but that only prints out a string. I'm assuming there behind the scenes it is a PyObject that is being serialized as a string. I would also like a confirmation that the function body is indeed stored in `c.names`.

2) Does marshal dump store the function as bytecode instructions or as a uncompiled literal? I'm leaning toward uncompiled literal as I searched for the opcode \x83 (RETURN_VALUE) and it only appears once in the dump. I believe this implies that there is only one return statement when there should be two: once to exit out of the function hello and once to return None for exiting the script.

Version

```
Python 2.7.13+ (heads/2.7:96f5020597, May 26 2017, 15:26:13)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: This is a lot of questions.

Comment: What do you even mean by "the `<code object hello at 0x1006c9230 ...>`"? You seem to mean something different from the code object, unless you're asking the rather silly question of how the code object stores the code object.

Comment: Yeah I was indeed asking how the code object stored the code object. For some reason I never thought of looking into `co.co_consts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down.

First, let me clarify how exactly CPython stores functions. When a function is parsed, CPython stores the function's data inside of a *code object*. CPython uses code objects to store functions, classes, and modules. The code object which represents the function is then *serialized* into a specific byte code format.

The code objects of function are stored in their `__code__` attributes:

```
>>> def foo():
    pass

>>> 
>>> foo.__code__
<code object foo at 0x7f8bd86ce5d0, file "<pyshell#14>", line 1>
>>>
```

These code objects contain various data related to the function such as the functions arguments, constants referenced(such as `1` or `"Hello"`), and name. The *bytecode* of the function is stored in the `.co_code` attribute. This is what is actually executed when CPython runs your function:

```
>>> def foo():
    pass

>>> foo.__code__.co_code
b'd\x00\x00S' # bytecode for foo
>>>
```

Now that you understand the basics of what CPython does, we can address your specific questions.

> Is there a way I can access the function body from the CPython code object. The closest I can get it c.names but that only prints out a string. I'm assuming there behind the scenes it is a PyObject that is being serialized as a string. I would also like a confirmation that the function body is indeed stored in c.names.

The function body ***is not*** stored in the `co_name` attribute of code objects. It is stored in the `.co_code` attribute as described above. You are also a little bit off in your other assumption. Technically, since all objects in Python "inherit" from `PyObject`, it would be correct to say the function body is serialized a `PyObject` serialized as a string. However, it'd be better to say that it is serialized as a `PyStringObject` which is the specific type the represents strings.

> Does marshal dump store the function as bytecode instructions or as a uncompiled literal? I'm leaning toward uncompiled literal as I searched for the opcode \x83 (RETURN_VALUE) and it only appears once in the dump. I believe this implies that there is only one return statement when there should be two: once to exit out of the function hello and once to return None for exiting the script.

It does neither. `marhsal.dumps()` takes a code object, serializes the entire code object into a CPython specific format, and returns a bytes object representing the serialized code object. However, your second statement is correct. At the end of every Python script, and implicit `None` is returned. This can be observed by passing an empty argument to `dis.dis()`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

> I know for a fact that `<code object hello at 0x1006c9230 ...>` is not stored in the co_code attribute of the original c. This is because no matter how I change the inside of def hello() the same disassembler output is given. To be clear this is a function inside a function/script not just a function as you gave in your example.

In the case of your specific example, the variable `c` is a code object which represents the *module* -  not the function - "hello.py". And your right, the code object for the *function* `hello()` is not in `co_code`. It is stored in the the module's code object's `co_consts` attribute:

```
>>> co = compile(open('hello.py').read(), 'hello.py', 'exec')
>>> co.co_consts
(<code object hello at 0x7fedcbd3dc00, file "hello.py", line 1>, 'hello', None)
>>>
```

This is because of how Python executes your code. Constants are not stored directly in a code object's bytecode. Rather, they are stored in their own separate tuple. Whenever a constant is referenced in a functions code, the actual constant is stored in `co_consts` and an *index* which corresponds to the position of said constant in `co_consts` is put in the byte code.

The reason why your disassembler output for `hello()`'s code object never changes is because all `dis.dis()` is doing is simply display the *string representation* for the `hello()` code object. The code object for `hello()` *does* change when you change the code, but that change is shown by `dis`.  It does not display the actual *changed* attributes of `hello()`s code object.

Comment: Ahh `co_consts`! Interesting. This seems to imply that `marshal.dump` stores the function as bytecode instructions as the fact that the co.co_consts's first index is a CPython code object means that it was actually compiled. Can you just confirm this? My new hypothesis is that I didn't see 2 \x83's originally because there is perhaps a different way to execute a return statement for `return 5` besides using that specific op code?

Comment: Actually nvm I just confirmed it myself. It seems like my mistake was thinking that \x83 is the same as 83 which is the RETURN opcode. In fact, 83 is 'S' not \x83 (which is actually a different decimal value). There are indeed two 'S''s in the marshal. Here is the code for confirmation: `>>> [ord(byte) for byte in co.co_consts[0].co_code]
[100, 1, 0, 125, 1, 0, 124, 1, 0, 83]`

Comment: @kshikama You are still a bit confused. Firstly, `marshal.dump()` does not store the function's byte-code instructions. `marhsal.dump()` receives a code object as a argument, _serializes_ the code object, and returns the serialized code object. And as for your second question. Yes there are two `\x83`s in the serialized code object. You can prove this by doing `marshal.dumps(c).count(b'\x83')` which returns `2`.

Comment: >>> import marshal
>>> marshal.dumps(co).count(b'\x83')
1

Comment: As mentioned in my earlier comment `>>> marshal.dumps(co).count('S')
2`. `\x83` is a different character. Anyways, that isn't too important in the context of this question. Thanks for your help Christian!

Comment: Actually one second. "does not store the function's byte-code instructions?" It does right? Here is the proof `>>> co.co_code in marshal.dumps(co)
True`.

Comment: @kshikama Yes, again you are correct. However, `marshal.dumps()` does not _**just**_ return the functions byte-code. It returns the _**serialized form of the functions code object**_, which _**does**_ contain the byte-code instructions for the function as well as other helpful data.

Comment: Ahh yes indeed.